# Class function return goes to another class function return print different value

Tags: c++, class

```
#include <iostream>

class Bender
{
  private:
    int y;
  public:
    void setY(double f)
    { y = f; }
    int getY() const
    { return y; }
};

class Bending
{
 private:
    Bender temp;
 public:
    int getTemp() const
    { return temp.getY();}
};

class Rodriguez
{
  private:
    Bending testing;
  public:
    int getTesting() const
    {return testing.getTemp();}
};

int main()
{
    Bender B;
    Bending Bend;
    Rodriguez R;

    B.setY(4);
    std::cout<<B.getY()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<Bend.getTemp()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<R.getTesting()<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

So, when I try to run this it prints 4, -272632440, 0(some garbage number), and I try to figure it out and I could not find the answer. It appears that the return value cannot be set to another return class return value

Comment: `Bend.temp.y` and `R.testing.temp.y` are not initialized. Reading from them is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Why do you expect the `Bender` inside `Bend` to be the same `Bender` as `B` from `main`?

Comment: The member variables don't belong to the classes, but to the instances of the classes. There are three instances of `Bender`, two of `Bending`, and one of `Rodriguez`.

Comment: Bender does not initialize y (leaving garbage in it until it's set via setY(), and 2) the Bender contained inside Bending and Rodriguez are never set, so return their initial garbage is all you get.

Comment: DIfferent Bender objects are different.  Just at `int x; int y;` are two different `int` objects.

Comment: Oh I see because it is all different object assign for each of the class and not the object that I wanted. Since some of the are never been assign and only the top one is assign to a value, it print garbage on the other two class.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs because you use `Bend` and `R` but never instantiate them.

Comment: They actually are used … which is part of the problem.

Comment: Yes, you are right! He used it, but never instantiated it.

Comment: Yes … So you may want to update your answer to clarify that.

Comment: it is instantiated, but not _initialized_.

Answer (score 1):

> It appears that the return value cannot be set to another return class return value

Actually, you can.
The reason why you're getting "garbage" numbers is because you're trying to access variables that have not been set. 
Variables are not set to 0 by default in C++. When you declare a variable, you're just reserving a space in memory and something might still be in that space if you don't overwrite it.
But I think the main problem here is that you don't understand the difference between a class and an **instance** of a class. Your Bender B is not the same as your Bender temp in your Bending class, they are 2 different objects.